# Discrepancy in photo shares on Facebook business page

Tags: facebook-pages

I have a small Facebook page on photography and have approximately 350 likes (or 'fans') on the page. Recently, I posted a photo of a wedding which somehow managed to garner more than 4,000 views. Using my personal computer, I can see that the image was shared by 3 other people, but using my Android manager app, it shows that the image was shared by 4 other people instead.

There might be some concerns regarding people's privacy and may affect what I can see regarding the photo being shared, but is there any way of finding out who the 4th person is and how it managed to generate so many views?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that someone may have shared it and then deleted it.  Sometimes the Android app takes longer to update.

The person could also have deleted their account potentially.

Otherwise I'm afraid I personally don't know of a way to find this out.  Have you tried googling the name of the file as saved on Facebook?

They can share your photos regardless of liking your page, if they have blocked you, they can still visit your profile or business page.  I would see no reason as to why you wouldn't want them to share it.